# Create relocatable package with proper autogenerated config cmake

Tags: cmake

I have created cmake target, say `A`, and want to install it and create a Config file, so that the installed package could be relocatable. My code is:

```
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
    FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake
    NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
    DESTINATION ??? )
```

Here, I am having a problem with the proper destination. I want the Config file to be installed where `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` points to. But when I put `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` at `???`, my resulting `ATargets.cmake` file contains the line:

```
set(_IMPORT_PREFIX "C:/Libraries/...")
```

which is the actual value of `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`. This `_IMPORT_PREFIX` is later prepended to the parameters of `set_target_properties()` command inside the auto-generated `ATargets.cmake`, resulting in hard coded paths, valid only on the installation system.

I tried to use some generator expressions like `<$IMPORT_PREFIX>` in place of `???`, but this gave me an error at cmake generation. I also tried to omit `DESTINATION` which in my opinion should place the file in the location relative to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`, but cmake complained about it too.

Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Package files generated by CMake are not intended to be relocatable. You may create relocatable package by writing "config" file by yourself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: well, according to the cmake docs: ```Packages created by install(EXPORT) are designed to be relocatable``` (source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-packages.7.html)

Comment: Hmm, not sure what they mean by "relocatable". However, you may try `.` (dot) or `./` as DESTINATION option for install files precisely under installation prefix. Such paths should be treated as relative by CMake, so "relocation" wouldn't suffer.

Comment: Ok. That helped a litte. I don't have absolute paths any longer. Unfortunately, there is still problem in the generated Target.cmake: to produce the _IMPORT_PREFIX it strips the filename component twice instead of once: ```get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)```. The paths produced in this way are still invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question so you have probably solved it already (or given up).

I think the critical thing is that the export DESTINATION matches the one  given to INSTALL_DESTINATION to configure_package_config_file().

what we are using is:

```
  install(TARGETS
    foobar
    EXPORT foobarLibTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
  set(ConfigFileInstallDir lib/cmake/foobar)
  set(INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR include)
  set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib)
  configure_package_config_file(src/main/cmake/foobarConfig.cmake.in
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarConfig.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION "${ConfigFileInstallDir}"
    PATH_VARS INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR)
  write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION "${VERSION}"
    COMPATIBILITY ExactVersion)
  export(EXPORT foobarLibTargets
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarLibTargets.cmake")
  install(EXPORT foobarLibTargets
    FILE foobarLibTargets.cmake
    DESTINATION "${ConfigFileInstallDir}")
  install(FILES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarConfig.cmake"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarConfigVersion.cmake"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarLibTargets.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${ConfigFileInstallDir}")
```

${ConfigFileInstallDir} is replaced automagically by _IMPORT_PREFIX
so that the generated foobarLibTargets.cmake contains something like:

```
set_property(TARGET foobar APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
set_target_properties(foobar PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/foobar.so.2.0.0"
  IMPORTED_SONAME_RELEASE "libfoobar.so.2"
)
```

There can be troubles getting this to work. See my questions:

- [correctly set the location of imported cmake targets for an installed package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56135785/1569204) &
- [Strange issue with variables in a config-file cmake package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56189739/1569204).

See you in the ward for those suffering from cmake related nervous disorders in the near future...